# Failed to sync signing identities with Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac

When I go in to Visual Studio for Mac -> Preferences -> Apple Developer Accounts and click “View Details…” I get the following error:

Failed to sync signing identities with Apple Developer Portal.
A parameter has an invalid value: A parameter ‘certificateType’ has an invalid value : ‘Unknown value: MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION’

Any idea how to resolve this? I can’t download my Provisioning Profiles.

I’m running Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.13 (build 11)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue , you can check it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-adding-Apple-Developer-Account:-A-/1426877.

And a fix for this issue has been released! You can install the most recent release from: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ .

For more, you can check [Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes).

Comment: I am already running the latest Version of Visual Studio(MAC) but the error persists.

Comment: You can first repair your visual studio .Please check:[Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) . If the problem persist, please try to [perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs).

Comment: Both Solutions didn't work

Comment: You can go to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41  for further support.